# Which linux-based firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall, router

We are looking to replace our current aging firewall/router with a new one.

We would prefer it to be free/opensource if possible.

Our minimum requirements would be:

```
1) Site-to-site VPN
2) Web URL/IP filtering
3) 2 WAN connections with load-balancing
4) Easy-to-use web inferface
```

Any suggestions? and why you chose yours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PFsense is easier solution for you. 
you may want to check monowall, ipfire (ipcop with 2.6 kernel) or untangle
but all of them except pfsense has no web gui for multiwan setup. 
in fact most of them is not supporting multiwan solutions.

but pfsense has different options for multiwan. 
because multiwan is not an easy to setup. it has many restrictions on connection.
here is some sources 
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN_Version_1.2.x

(Andrew, this thing is not allowing me to vote up or comment. 
that's why i wrote as new answer)

Comment: Ah yes, the joys of the reputation system... +1 for putting in more explanation than I had time for!

Comment: pfSense has no native web filtering solution, OpenDNS might do the job.

Comment: With plugins. Squid & dansguardian can be installed easily with a few clicks. & all sort of url filter & blacklists like shalla can be applied via plugins. OpenDNS can be a problem when you have too many clients. it has limits to query which can exceeded so fast.

Comment: +1 Note, pfSense and M0n0wall are both FreeBSD based, which is not Linux.

Answer (score 5):

[pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) is what I'm trialling at the moment, based on a [similar question I had](https://serverfault.com/questions/140517/linux-router-and-firewall-with-ip-accounting). It's FreeBSD based but seems to do everything we need (and I think it does everything you want). You can also look at things like Endian Firewall, SmoothWall, eBox Platform, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Untangle is free and OSS, with premium subscriptions for load balancing and more robust web filtering - http://www.untangle.com - available on 14-day free trials.

Recommended top Content filter by Spiceworks community, too.

Disclaimer: I work for Untangle, so please try it out for yourself, don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for... [IPCop](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ipcop/wiki)!

Seriously, IPCop rawks. It has a massive array of plugins, is easier than falling off a log to use and it even runs off of a CD if you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about the load balancing, but as a standalone nix solution. I am really like the Endian Community Firewall.

http://www.endian.com/en/community/overview/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/), which is not Linux based, but BSD comes close to it, I think.

I myself use OpenBSD, but m0m0wall is what I suggest for users that need quick setup and a nice interface.